# Image getting downloaded but not getting shown in the gallery

Tags: android, uri

I'm trying to download Image using [PRDownloader](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/PRDownloader).

Here's my code:

```
int downloadId = PRDownloader.download(photo.getUrls().getFull(), mContext.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/Folder/", photo.getId())
                                .build()
                                .setOnStartOrResumeListener(new OnStartOrResumeListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onStartOrResume() {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setOnPauseListener(new OnPauseListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPause() {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Download paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancel() {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Download cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onProgress(Progress progress) {
                                        mProgressDialog.show();
                                    }
                                })
                                .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDownloadComplete() {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Image saved in gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Error error) {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Error downloading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
```

This Toast: `Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Image saved in gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` is getting executed but the downloaded image is not getting shown in the gallery or anywhere in the device.

What's wrong here?

Comment: You wrote that error message is showing,then how it will be available on gallery??

Comment: @Md.ibrahimkhalil thanks for pointing it out. It was a silly mistake. I've edited the question. I'm getting the `Toast` which is in `onDownloadComplete()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with changing your path. I think it's issue with your path. Please try below path of download directory or any other path if you want to.
(I don't know you are testing with emulator or real device but you should try with real device as well)

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to give permission in the manifest as well as ask at runtime

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

After that when you file or image will be downloaded successfully send a broadcast to device media scanner:

```
mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

this will notify the device for newly added files.

Comment: error coming up: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED`